# how to convert datetime csharp to javascript date in view asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a dateTime field that holds end dateTime of the exam. It's comes from database.
I want to create countdown timer with this field.I have the countdown timer code but I don't know how to use end dateTime.
This is javascript code:

```
 var countDownDate = new Date(Date.parse(endTime));

    var x = setInterval(function () {

        // Get today's date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is finished, write some text
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }
    }, 1000);
```

this is the endTime in my view:

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "ShowQuestions";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
DateTime start = ViewBag.StartTime;
DateTime endTime = ViewBag.EndTime;
 }
```

When I run this,it shows nothing.What should I write in :

```
var countDownDate=...
```

Comment: user '@' for server side code. ```var end = @endtime var countDownDate = new Date(Date.parse(end)); ```

Comment: Thank's but it doesn't work.It doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the @ character as follows:
var countDownDate = new Date(Date.parse(@endTime))
Or
var countDownDate = new Date(Date.parse('@Html.Raw(endTime)'))

Answer (score 0):

Dont send c# datatime response in frontend application, Send datetime string format yyyy-mm-dd format response

Comment: Thank's but how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier if you just converted to a JavaScript date on the C# side of things.

A JavaScript Date is a number that tells the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC. This is like the Unix epoch time except that Unix epoch is expressed in seconds rather than milliseconds. Now, the DateTime class as you are using it refers to machine time (or local time depending on how the machine is configured). It cannot be converted directly to a JavaScript time unless you take the time zone into account.

The DateTimeOffset class takes care of all this for you. That class contains the local time and the offset to UTC time. It has a method to that takes its value and returns it as a long that is compatible with a JavaScript Date object. This doesn't work for you directly though because you are receiving a DateTime from the database. (I'll ignore the fact that storing a DateTime in the database instead of a DateTimeOffset is bad form. :-) )

Fortunately, You can convert a DateTime to a to a DateTimeOffset. [Convert from DateTime to DateTImeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-datetime-and-offset).

The code below illustrates getting a DateTimeOffset for the current time and printing it out as a JavaScript Date compatible number.  It also shows you how easy it is to convert a DateTime struct to a DateTimeOffset struct, assuming you are willing to simply accept the local time zone to create the offset from UTC. In your case, you simply want a countdown timer, so that will be fine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        Console.WriteLine($"Current time expressed as a JavaScript Date is {dateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()}");

        var now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTimeOffset nowDateTimeOffset = now;
        Console.WriteLine($"Current time expressed as a JavaScript Date after conversion is  {nowDateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()}");
    }
}
```